# Spring integration errorChannel no messages in JUnit

Tags: error-handling, junit4, spring-integration, spring-junit

I have a simple JUnit test in which I am testing `errorChannel` by hooking up a `service activator`. However, nothing comes to this channel
the config is as follows,

```
<int:channel id="in"/>

<int:service-activator id="inSA" input-channel="in" ref="thrower" 
      output-channel="nullChannel"/>
          <bean id="thrower" 
class="com.att.datalake.ifr.loader.exceptions.handler.Thrower" />

<int:service-activator input-channel="errorChannel" ref="errorManager" 
        id="errorMgr" method="handleMessage" />

<bean id="errorManager" 
    class="com.att.datalake.ifr.loader.exceptions.handlers.ErrorManager"/>
```

The ErrorMgr is as follows:

```
public class ErrorManager {
@ServiceActivator
public void handleMessage(Message<MessageHandlingException> exception) {
    System.out.println("In cleaner");

}
```

}

The Thrower class is as follows:

```
public class Thrower {

public Message<FileMessage> process(final Message<FileMessage> message) throws PublisherException {
    System.out.println("In the Thrower SA at:"+new Date());
    // get error type
    String errorType = (String) message.getHeaders().get("ERROR_TYPE");
    if (errorType.equals("PublisherError")) {
        System.out.println("*****About to throw");
        throw new PublisherException("Simple Publisher Exception at:"+new Date());
    }
    return message;
  }
}
```

The Thrower SA simply throws an exception, which is reported by JUnit test, but nothing goes to `errorChannel`

The log in debug is :

```
2015-01-23 10:53:20.597 DEBUG   --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry'
2015-01-23 10:53:20.597 DEBUG   --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'globalChannelInterceptorProcessor'
2015-01-23 10:53:20.598 DEBUG   --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'inSA'
2015-01-23 10:53:20.598 DEBUG   --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'errorMgr'
2015-01-23 10:53:20.598 DEBUG   --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
2015-01-23 10:53:20.598 DEBUG   --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
2015-01-23 10:53:20.599  INFO   --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase -2147483648
2015-01-23 10:53:20.600 DEBUG   --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting bean 'globalChannelInterceptorProcessor' of type [class org.springframework.integration.config.GlobalChannelInterceptorProcessor]
2015-01-23 10:53:20.602 DEBUG   --- [           main] .s.i.c.GlobalChannelInterceptorProcessor : No global channel interceptors.
2015-01-23 10:53:20.603 DEBUG   --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Successfully started bean 'globalChannelInterceptorProcessor'
2015-01-23 10:53:20.604  INFO   --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
2015-01-23 10:53:20.605 DEBUG   --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting bean 'inSA' of type [class org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean]
2015-01-23 10:53:20.605  INFO   --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {service-activator:inSA} as a subscriber to the 'in' channel
2015-01-23 10:53:20.606  INFO   --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@6f3b5d16.in' has 1 subscriber(s).
2015-01-23 10:53:20.606  INFO   --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started inSA
2015-01-23 10:53:20.606 DEBUG   --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Successfully started bean 'inSA'
2015-01-23 10:53:20.606 DEBUG   --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting bean 'errorMgr' of type [class org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean]
2015-01-23 10:53:20.607  INFO   --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {service-activator:errorMgr} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2015-01-23 10:53:20.607  INFO   --- [           main] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@6f3b5d16.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2015-01-23 10:53:20.607  INFO   --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started errorMgr
2015-01-23 10:53:20.607 DEBUG   --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Successfully started bean 'errorMgr'
2015-01-23 10:53:20.607 DEBUG   --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger' of type [class org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean]
2015-01-23 10:53:20.607  INFO   --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2015-01-23 10:53:20.607  INFO   --- [           main] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@6f3b5d16.errorChannel' has 2 subscriber(s).
2015-01-23 10:53:20.607  INFO   --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
2015-01-23 10:53:20.608 DEBUG   --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Successfully started bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
2015-01-23 10:53:20.610 DEBUG   --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.IdGeneratorConfigurer#0'
2015-01-23 10:53:20.612 DEBUG   --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemProperties]
2015-01-23 10:53:20.612 DEBUG   --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemEnvironment]
2015-01-23 10:53:20.613 DEBUG   --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Could not find key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in any property source. Returning [null]
2015-01-23 10:53:20.614 DEBUG   --- [           main] c.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate : Storing ApplicationContext in cache under key [[MergedContextConfiguration@105fece7 testClass = ErrorHandlerTests, locations = '{classpath:com/att/datalake/ifr/loader/flowtests/ErrorHandlerTests-context.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]
2015-01-23 10:53:20.615 DEBUG   --- [           main] org.springframework.test.context.cache   : Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics: [ContextCache@7a1a14a4 size = 1, hitCount = 0, missCount = 1, parentContextCount = 0]
2015-01-23 10:53:20.620 DEBUG   --- [           main] o.s.b.f.annotation.InjectionMetadata     : Processing injected method of bean 'com.att.datalake.ifr.loader.flowtests.ErrorHandlerTests': AutowiredFieldElement for private org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel com.att.datalake.ifr.loader.flowtests.ErrorHandlerTests.in
2015-01-23 10:53:20.623 DEBUG   --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'in'
2015-01-23 10:53:20.623 DEBUG   --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'nullChannel'
2015-01-23 10:53:20.624 DEBUG   --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'errorChannel'
2015-01-23 10:53:20.625 DEBUG   --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Autowiring by type from bean name 'com.att.datalake.ifr.loader.flowtests.ErrorHandlerTests' to bean named 'in'
2015-01-23 10:53:20.642 DEBUG   --- [           main] o.s.i.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler   : ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@49ff7d8c] (inSA) received message: GenericMessage [payload=FileMessage [name=2.txt, path=input/2.txt], headers={ERROR_TYPE=PublisherError, correlationId=1, id=dd662ff5-9790-77e2-cceb-f43afc97de81, timestamp=1422028400642}]
In the Thrower SA at:Fri Jan 23 10:53:20 EST 2015
*****About to throw
2015-01-23 10:53:20.648 DEBUG   --- [           main] .c.s.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener : After test method: context [DefaultTestContext@40e6dfe1 testClass = ErrorHandlerTests, testInstance = com.att.datalake.ifr.loader.flowtests.ErrorHandlerTests@1b083826, testMethod = test@ErrorHandlerTests, testException = org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: ; nested exception is com.att.datalake.ifr.loader.exceptions.PublisherException: Simple Publisher Exception at:Fri Jan 23 10:53:20 EST 2015, mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@105fece7 testClass = ErrorHandlerTests, locations = '{classpath:com/att/datalake/ifr/loader/flowtests/ErrorHandlerTests-context.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]], class dirties context [false], class mode [null], method dirties context [false].
2015-01-23 10:53:20.657 DEBUG   --- [           main] .c.s.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener : After test class: context [DefaultTestContext@40e6dfe1 testClass = ErrorHandlerTests, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@105fece7 testClass = ErrorHandlerTests, locations = '{classpath:com/att/datalake/ifr/loader/flowtests/ErrorHandlerTests-context.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]], dirtiesContext [false].
2015-01-23 10:53:20.662  INFO   --- [       Thread-0] o.s.c.support.GenericApplicationContext  : Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@6f3b5d16: startup date [Fri Jan 23 10:53:19 EST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-01-23 10:53:20.663 DEBUG   --- [       Thread-0] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.IdGeneratorConfigurer#0'
2015-01-23 10:53:20.664 DEBUG   --- [       Thread-0] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry'
2015-01-23 10:53:20.664 DEBUG   --- [       Thread-0] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'globalChannelInterceptorProcessor'
2015-01-23 10:53:20.664 DEBUG   --- [       Thread-0] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'inSA'
2015-01-23 10:53:20.664 DEBUG   --- [       Thread-0] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'errorMgr'
2015-01-23 10:53:20.664 DEBUG   --- [       Thread-0] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
2015-01-23 10:53:20.665 DEBUG   --- [       Thread-0] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
2015-01-23 10:53:20.665  INFO   --- [       Thread-0] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 0
2015-01-23 10:53:20.666 DEBUG   --- [       Thread-0] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Asking bean 'inSA' of type [class org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean] to stop
2015-01-23 10:53:20.667  INFO   --- [       Thread-0] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing {service-activator:inSA} as a subscriber to the 'in' channel
2015-01-23 10:53:20.667  INFO   --- [       Thread-0] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@6f3b5d16.in' has 0 subscriber(s).
2015-01-23 10:53:20.667 DEBUG   --- [       Thread-0] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Bean 'inSA' completed its stop procedure
2015-01-23 10:53:20.667  INFO   --- [       Thread-0] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : stopped inSA
2015-01-23 10:53:20.667 DEBUG   --- [       Thread-0] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Asking bean 'errorMgr' of type [class org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean] to stop
2015-01-23 10:53:20.667  INFO   --- [       Thread-0] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing {service-activator:errorMgr} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2015-01-23 10:53:20.667  INFO   --- [       Thread-0] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@6f3b5d16.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2015-01-23 10:53:20.668 DEBUG   --- [       Thread-0] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Bean 'errorMgr' completed its stop procedure
2015-01-23 10:53:20.668  INFO   --- [       Thread-0] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : stopped errorMgr
2015-01-23 10:53:20.668 DEBUG   --- [       Thread-0] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Asking bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger' of type [class org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean] to stop
2015-01-23 10:53:20.668  INFO   --- [       Thread-0] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2015-01-23 10:53:20.668  INFO   --- [       Thread-0] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@6f3b5d16.errorChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
2015-01-23 10:53:20.668 DEBUG   --- [       Thread-0] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger' completed its stop procedure
2015-01-23 10:53:20.668  INFO   --- [       Thread-0] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : stopped _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
2015-01-23 10:53:20.668  INFO   --- [       Thread-0] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase -2147483648
2015-01-23 10:53:20.668 DEBUG   --- [       Thread-0] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@25ce9dc4: defining beans [org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer#0,channelInitializer,$autoCreateChannelCandidates,IntegrationConfigurationBeanFactoryPostProcessor,integrationEvaluationContext,org.springframework.integration.expression.IntegrationEvaluationContextAwareBeanPostProcessor#0,integrationGlobalProperties,integrationHeaderChannelRegistry,globalChannelInterceptorProcessor,toStringFriendlyJsonNodeToStringConverter,converterRegistrar,integrationConversionService,DefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor,datatypeChannelMessageConverter,messageBuilderFactory,in,org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#0,inSA,thrower,org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#1,fixedSubscriberChannelBeanFactoryPostProcessor,errorMgr,errorManager,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor,nullChannel,errorChannel,_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger,taskScheduler,org.springframework.integration.config.IdGeneratorConfigurer#0]; root of factory hierarchy
2015-01-23 10:53:20.694 DEBUG   --- [       Thread-0] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean '(inner bean)#74589991': [_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger]
2015-01-23 10:53:20.696 DEBUG   --- [       Thread-0] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'in': [com.att.datalake.ifr.loader.flowtests.ErrorHandlerTests]
2015-01-23 10:53:20.697 DEBUG   --- [       Thread-0] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'taskScheduler'
2015-01-23 10:53:20.698  INFO   --- [       Thread-0] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2015-01-23 10:53:20.699 DEBUG   --- [       Thread-0] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean '(inner bean)#4b213651': [taskScheduler]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ErrorMessage` with an `Exception` is thrown to the `error-channel` only if the downstream flow is within the separate `Thread`. Otherwise the `Exception` is rethrown to the call. It is thrown to the caller anyway, but shifted to the `error-channel`, if there is no original caller control from Spring Integration.

See more info here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-errorhandler

Comment: ok thanks, makes sense. I made the upstream channel a queue channel and now the Exceptions thrown are going to the errorChannel. thanks much.